# Good HTML Templates for form based Web Applications

Tags: html

I would like to refer HTML templates designed/developed especially for form based Web Applications.

I have been searching them but am not able to find out which I find better.

Regards,
Jatan

Answer (score 2):

Much of the choice in this sort of thing is going to be defined by your choice of server tech / platform, e.g. .NET has in built widgets you can use, as do many web application frameworks.

The django admin layouts are extremely well designed, you could download [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and check it out.

Similar forms are also implemented for Rails by the [Streamlined framwork](http://streamlinedframework.org/), not to mention the inbuilt scaffolding generators.

Tthe YUI framework has a bunch of different widgets with a consistent style, as does the ExtJS framework, and are server technology agnostic. These can be dynamically created using json as the data source, rather than html/xml

You could also use a CSS framework such as BlueprintCSS, and combine it with the suggested HTML, and add effects + interactions with jQuery, and build that on top of your html.

Modifying an existing layout is not too hard, for a simple CRUD application you probably just need a large area for forms and lists/tables and a menu.

If you need anything more particular than that, its probably time to invest in a design, or learn to do it yourself.

The simplest possible layout is going to be a header with a menu inside (& maybe a heading), and a content area for your forms.

---

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    div#page { width:900px; margin:0; auto; }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <!-- Menu Goes Here! -->
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <!-- Put some Forms n stuff here -->
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few catalogs of template designs:

- [Open Design Community](http://www.opendesigns.org/)
- [Open Web Design](http://www.openwebdesign.org/)
- [Open Source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I create one, maybe you will find it useful => [web application admin template](https://github.com/williamn/web-application-admin-template)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [ThemeForest](http://themeforest.net/).  They have a large selection and includes the raw markup and css scripts so you can make your forms app look like the template in no time.